# Printing to specific (runtime-determined) precision in Julia

Tags: printing, decimal, julia, rounding, decimal-point

Given a value x and an integer n (assigned at runtime), I want to print x to exactly n digits after the decimal (after rounding if needed).

`print(round(x, n))` works fine for `(x,n)=(3.141592, 3)` but for `(x,n)=(2.5,5)`, it prints just `2.5`, not `2.50000` (5 digits after decimal point).

If I knew n at runtime, say 5, I could do

```
@printf("%.5f", x)
```

But @printf being a macro needs n to be known at compile time.

Is this possible using some `show` magic or something else?

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaIO/Formatting.jl and https://github.com/IainNZ/Humanize.jl

Comment: it is odd and unfortunate that julia does not support the unix-standard of using `*` as a width modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Using the fresh new [Format.jl](https://github.com/JuliaString/Format.jl) package:

```
using Format

function foo(x, n)
    f = FormatSpec(".$(n)f")
    pyfmt(f, x)
end

foo(2.5, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, for some reason the julia version of @printf / @sprintf do not support the "width" sub-specifier as per the c printf standard (see `man 3 printf`).

If you're feeling brave, you can rely on the c sprintf which supports the "dynamic width" modifier, to collect a string that you then just print as normal.

```julia
A = Vector{UInt8}(100); # initialise array of 100 "chars"
ccall( :sprintf, Int32, (Ptr{UInt8}, Cstring, Int64, Float64), A, "%.*f", 4, 0.1 )
print( unsafe_string(pointer(A)) )    #> 0.1000
```

Note the asterisk in `%.*f`, and the extra input `4` serving as the dynamic width modifier.

Comment: Ha, I'd never in a million years would have thought of using `ccall` for this. I'll probably never resort to this method, but props to you for creative problem solving!