# how to create a thin wrapper around array of strings C

Tags: julia

when using Julia calling C, it is very nice that Julia can provide a thin wrapper around existing data allocated by C, which makes the data exchange efficiently between C and Julia. And here is the famous online example in Julia embedding section:

```
double *existingArray = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*10);
jl_array_t *x = jl_ptr_to_array_1d(array_type, existingArray, 10, 0);
```

the question I have is: can Julia gurus provide an example illustrating how to create a thin wrapper around existing array of strings (already allocated on heap in C)

A follow-up question is: do we also need to take care of write barriers in some way? since the array of strings is basically an array of pointers,

Another question is: how Julia does gc handling when the underlying data is an array of strings: i.e. array of pointers, each pointer pointing to the starting address of a null-terminated string.

Many thanks!!!

Zhiyuan

Comment: Are you looking for unsafe_wrap and unsafe_string?  You can use GC.@preserve to prevent the C string array from being gc-ed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that Julia 0.5.2 does not complain the following approach :

suppose that in C/C++ you have :

char* pchar points to “A is s\0B is so\0C is som\0D is some\0”, size : 34 = size_all

and

char** myStrArray has 4 pointers : pointing to the location of "A", "B", "C", D",

and the goal is to pass pchar and myStrArray back to Julia without copying so that in Julia somehow you have an array of string :

{ "A is s", "B is so", "C is som", "D is some" }

**in the C/C++ portion :**

```
jl_value_t* array_type_pointer = jl_apply_array_type(jl_voidpointer_type, 1);
jl_array_t* str_array = jl_ptr_to_array_1d( array_type_pointer, (void*)myStrArray, 4, 1 );
jl_set_nth_field(ret, 14, (jl_value_t*)str_array );

jl_value_t* array_type_uint8 = jl_apply_array_type(jl_uint8_type, 1);
jl_array_t* chr_array = jl_ptr_to_array_1d( array_type_uint8, (uint8_t*)pchar, size_all, 1 );
jl_set_nth_field(ret, 13, (jl_value_t*)chr_array );
```

Notice that in jl_ptr_to_array_1d call, the last param := 1, which means that Julia owns the buffer.

**in Julia portion**

you declare the following two :

```
StrVec::Array
StrVecPtr::Array
```

both of the above two belong to ret1, say.

```
julia> String(copy( ret1.StrVec ) )
"A is s\0B is so\0C is som\0D is some\0"

julia> ret1.StrVecPtr
4-element Array{Ptr{Void},1}:
 Ptr{Void} @0x000000000404aa00
 Ptr{Void} @0x000000000404aa07
 Ptr{Void} @0x000000000404aa0f
 Ptr{Void} @0x000000000404aa18

julia> unsafe_string( convert( Ptr{UInt8}, ret1.StrVecPtr[1] ) )
"A is s"

julia> unsafe_string( convert( Ptr{UInt8}, ret1.StrVecPtr[2] ) )
"B is so"

julia> unsafe_string( convert( Ptr{UInt8}, ret1.StrVecPtr[3] ) )
"C is som"

julia> unsafe_string( convert( Ptr{UInt8}, ret1.StrVecPtr[4] ) )
"D is some"
```

Remarks : the contents are contained in an array of UInt8, separated by '\0', contiguous in memory, making it easier to do gc after all.

If someone spots some errors, or have alternative ways, please post.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I have understood your question exactly, but I thought my recent answer to an unrelated question may also be relevant here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50747086/4183191